# onsubmit validateForm funxtion is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

here for validation i used onsubmit event.
but any how its not working.
i just want check that textbox  filed is empty or not.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>temple3</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="temple3css.css">
           <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="popup-content" class='container'>
    <div id="container1">
    <form id="form" class="form"  onsubmit="return validateForm()">

    <h1>Feedbak Form</h1>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="intro"></div>
        <div id="section0" >
            <div class="field roption">
            <input type="radio" name="view" value="public"  checked="checked"> <span>Public</span>
            <input type="radio" name="view" value="private" ><span>Private</span>
            </div>
            <div class="field category">
            <label for>Category:</label>
            <select class="dropDownCate" autofocus>
            <option value="bug">Bug</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            </select>
            </div>
            <div class="field message">
            <label for="Comments">Comments:</label>
            <textarea id="comments" name="Comments" placeholder='Your Feedback Here!' autofocus></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
            <label for="Email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="Email" placeholder="example@stevens.edu(optional)" autofocus>
            </div>
            <div class="field"><input type="submit" id="submit-feedback-button"  autofocus></div>
        </div>
    </div>

</form>
 </div>
    </div>
 <div id="popup-overlay-bg"> </div> 
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function validateForm(){
                var texbox=document.getElementById("comments").value;
                if(texbox == "") {
                    document.getElementById("comments").focus();
                    // document.getElementById("comments").style.border = "1px solid #ff0000";
                    return false;
                }
            }
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#feedback-button").click(function(){
               openfeedbackform();
            });
           $("#popup-overlay-bg").click(function(){
               closefeedbackform();
           });
            $("#submit-feedback-button").click(function(){
               // closefeedbackform();
            });
            $(window).resize(function(){
              updatefeedbackform();   
            });
                $("#submit-feedback-button").click(function(){
                 var category=$(".dropDownCate").val();
                 var  roption=$('input:radio[name=view]:checked').val();
                 var message=$("#comments").val();
                 var email=$("#email").val();

                    $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "feedback.php",
                  data: "category="+category+ "&roption="+roption+ "&message="+message+ "&email="+email,

                  success:function(result)
                  {
                    if(result=="true"){
                      $("#form").hide();
                        $("#container1").html("<h3>Thank you for your feedback We will get back to you ASAP</h3> ");
                    }
                    else{
                         $("#form").hide();
                      $("#container1").html("<h3> database error </h3>");
                    }
                  }
                 });
                    return false;
            });

        });
             function openfeedbackform(){
                 $("#popup-content").find('input:text').val('');
                 $("#popup-content").fadeIn();
                 $("#popup-overlay-bg").fadeIn();
                 updatefeedbackform();
             }
            function updatefeedbackform(){
                $popup=$("#popup-content");
                var top = "50px";
                var left = ($(window).width() - $popup.outerWidth()) / 2;
    $popup.css({
        'top' : top,
        'left' : left
    });
            }
            function closefeedbackform(){
                  $("#popup-content").fadeOut();
                $("#popup-overlay-bg").fadeOut();
            } 
        </script>   
    </body>
    </html>
```

earlier i  used same this for form validation. but i don't why its not working here. i tried to debug but function has not been call.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you are doing ajax submit in the button click event, not in the form submit.

The click handler is triggered before the submit event handler, so the validation does not have any effect.

The solution will be to use the form submit event handler for both validation and the ajax call as given below, and then there is no need to have the inline event handler like `onsubmit="return validateForm()"`

```
$("#form").submit(function () {
    if (validateForm() === false) {
        return false;
    }

    var category = $(".dropDownCate").val();
    var roption = $('input:radio[name=view]:checked').val();
    var message = $("#comments").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "feedback.php",
        data: "category=" + category + "&roption=" + roption + "&message=" + message + "&email=" + email,

        success: function (result) {
            if (result == "true") {
                $("#form").hide();
                $("#container1").html("<h3>Thank you for your feedback We will get back to you ASAP</h3> ");
            } else {
                $("#form").hide();
                $("#container1").html("<h3> database error </h3>");
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: @SagarShah `$("#submit-feedback-button").click(function(){` is changed to `$("#form").submit(function () {`

Comment: if (!validateForm() === false) {
        return false;
    } need to remove !. otherwise it works good than you once again